# How do you prevent a re-created React component from losing state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

The example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-sandbox-forked-7kfhs?file=/src/App.js) is a contrived example, but it illustrates the point.

Clicking the "Add column" button is supposed to add a new column. It works the first time, but doesn't work after that. You'll notice from the log that this issue has to do with the fact that `columns` is always in its original state. Therefore, a column is always being added to this original state, not the current state.

I imagine this issue is related to the fact that the column header is being re-created on each call to `renderHeader`, but I'm unsure about how to pass the state to the newly created header component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to update your state:

- The first way:
  setColumns(newColumns)
- The second way:
  setColumns(columns => newColumns)

You should use the second way because the new state depend on the current state.

```
onClick={() => {
  setColumns((columns) => {
    console.log(columns.map((column) => column.field));
    const newColumnName = `Column ${columns.length}`;
    const newColumns = [...columns];
    newColumns.splice(
      columns.length - 1,
      0,
      createColumn(newColumnName)
    );
    return newColumns;
  });
}}
```

Your component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [rows] = useState([
    { id: 1, "Column 1": 1, "Column 2": 2 },
    { id: 2, "Column 1": 3, "Column 2": 3 },
    { id: 3, "Column 1": 4, "Column 2": 5 }
  ]);
  const createColumn = (name) => {
    return {
      field: name,
      align: "center",
      editable: true,
      sortable: false
    };
  };
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    createColumn("Column 1"),
    createColumn("Column 2"),
    {
      field: "Add a split",
      width: 150,
      sortable: false,
      renderHeader: (params) => {
        return (
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setColumns((columns) => { // <== use callback
                console.log(columns.map((column) => column.field));
                const newColumnName = `Column ${columns.length}`;
                const newColumns = [...columns];
                newColumns.splice(
                  columns.length - 1,
                  0,
                  createColumn(newColumnName)
                );
                return newColumns;
              });
            }}
          >
            Add column
          </Button>
        );
      }
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataGrid
        className="App-data-grid"
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnMenu
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-sandbox-forked-1im0p?file=/src/App.js:0-1562

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I do have one follow-up question, though: how I would solve this same issue with the component's props? For example, if I added `disabled={columns.length >= 4}` as a prop on the button, I would expect it to disable the "Add column" button if there are 4 or more columns. However, `columns` there is still referencing the original state.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the way the closure for `(params) => {...}` captures the value of `columns`. At the same time, you have this strange circular thing going on: `useState()` returns `columns` and also uses `columns` in one of its parameters. You will need to find a way to break this circularity.