# State not updating on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I need to update the player state on click (setPlayerState) but it's not being doing on time. I mean, it updates later on, so I get the first state only after the second click when the state has changed again. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
  const [player, setPlayerState] = useState({
    name,
    assertions: 0,
    score: 0,
    gravatarEmail,
  });

  function handleClick({ target }) {
    const id = target.getAttribute('data-testid').includes('correct');
    let points = 0;
    if (id) {
      const level = questions[index].difficulty;
      if (level === 'hard') points = THREE;
      else if (level === 'medium') points = TWO;
      else points = ONE;
      setPlayerState({
        ...player,
        assertions: player.assertions + 1,
        score: player.score + (TEN + (timer * points)),
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Need more code. Could you please add the relevant parts of the component? Like the stuff which is rendered.

Comment: This can help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71053123/how-do-you-prevent-a-re-created-react-component-from-losing-state/71053288#71053288

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you prevent a re-created React component from losing state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71053123/how-do-you-prevent-a-re-created-react-component-from-losing-state)

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil I have seen that post, but no idea how to do on mine, it seems different case.

Comment: I think it's the same case, the way of updating the state is wrong. I posted the answer.

Comment: It will be better if you can post the whole component.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil the component is huge, no way to post. Anyway if I use setPlayerState outside the function, it works, but I need to update only on that if condition, this is why should be made inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click state and `useEffect` to respond to it's change. It effectively forces two passes for the re-render.

Also try setPlayerState with previous value parameter i.e `setPlayerState(player =>`  which sometimes helps when updates are not noticed.

```js
  const [player, setPlayerState] = useState({
    name,
    assertions: 0,
    score: 0,
    gravatarEmail,
  });

  const [clickTarget, setClickTarget] = useState(null)

  function handleClick({ target }) {
    setClickTarget(target )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!clickTarget) return

    const id = clickTarget.getAttribute('data-testid').includes('correct');
    let points = 0;
    if (id) {
      const level = questions[index].difficulty;

      points = (level === 'hard') ? THREE :
        (level === 'medium') ? TWO : ONE;

      setPlayerState(player => ({
        ...player,
        assertions: player.assertions + 1,
        score: player.score + (TEN + (timer * points)),
      }))
    }
    setClickTarget(null)
  }, [clickTarget])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points in your codes stand out

- You reference `index` inside of your `if(id) ...` conditional but `index` is not set.
- `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`, and `TEN` are not set.
- Question scoring logic is tangled with state update logic

Here is a minimal complete example that fixes these things and shows a better way to write `onClick`. Run the code example and click the <kbd>question</kbd> buttons to see how `assertions` and `score` updates respectively.

```js
function App({ questions = [] }) {
  const [player, setPlayer] = React.useState({
    name: "Hanna",
    assertions: 0,
    score: 0,
  })
  function calcScore(difficulty) {
    switch (difficulty) {
      case "hard": return 3
      case "medium": return 2
      default: return 1
    }
  }
  function onClick(question) { return event => {
    if (event.target.getAttribute("data-test-id").includes("correct"))
      setPlayer({
        ...player,
        assertions: player.assertions + 1,
        score: player.score + calcScore(question.difficulty)
      })
  }}
  return <div>
    {questions.map((q, key) =>
      <button key={key} data-test-id="correct" onClick={onClick(q)}>
        {q.ask}
      </button>
    )}
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(player, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}
const questions = [
  { ask: "What is?", difficulty: "easy" },
  { ask: "How come?", difficulty: "medium" },
  { ask: "Seriously?", difficulty: "hard" }
]
ReactDOM.render(<App questions={questions} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace **setState** function called with the below code block to make sure **state** updated:

```
setPlayerState(s => ({
    ...s,
    assertions: s.assertions + 1,
    score: s.score + (TEN + (timer * points)),
}));
```